# Programmatically Modifying the Default Physical File Location of the Default Web Site (IIS 6.0)

Tags: c#, web, location, iis-6, default

How do I programmatically (using C#) modify the Default Physical File Location of the Default Web Site in IIS 6.0 ?

MSDN has [an article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1c1d212b-18ae-414a-b5ec-eaf5b000a0c3.mspx?mfr=true) regarding this.

*You can use the Home Directory tab of the Web Site Properties dialog box to specify the path to the home directory for your Web site and whether the home directory resides on the local computer or on a network computer. The default Web site home directory is SystemDrive:\Inetpub\Wwwroot.*

**How do I achieve this programmatically ?**

Update: I can do it in IIS 7 and higher using [ServerManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Class. I reseached a lot but couldn't find a specific way to do this in IIS 6. Any help will be really appreciated.

Here is how I did it in IIS 7

```
using (ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager())
 {
   var site = iisManager.Sites["Default Web Site"];
   site.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath = "C:\MyFolder";
   site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = "DefaultAppPool";
   site.ServerAutoStart = true;
   iisManager.CommitChanges();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Microsoft.Web.Administration`

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
serverManager.remove("yoursitename");
serverManager.Update();
serverManager.Sites.Add("yoursitename", "protocol", "port", "yourNewLocation");
serverManager.Update();
```

But, I think it will work with only IIS7+

Comment: Yes, I've used that dll to achieve what I want in IIS 7 or higher. I want something that works for IIS 6. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this will help you in IIS 6. You'll need to find what the property name is for physical file location in order to set it but this should do the trick. 1 in the metabasePath variable is the id of the site in IIS - the default web site may have something different so check it. this is written in VB.net but translating it to C# is a simple task.

```
dim metabasePath as String = "IIS://localhost/W3svc/1"
Private Sub SetProperty(ByVal metabasePath As String, ByVal propertyName As String, ByVal newValue As Object, clearCurrentValue As Boolean)
        Dim path As DirectoryEntry
        path = New DirectoryEntry(metabasePath)
        If clearCurrentValue Then path.Properties(propertyName).Clear()
        path.Properties(propertyName).Add(newValue)
        path.CommitChanges()
End Sub
```

Comment: managing IIS6 through code is horrendously difficult in some areas (and broken in others from what I've found on the internet).